# Xcode 9 not updating ionic 2 ios app appicons

Tags: android, ios, xcode, ionic2, ionic3

I'm creating a ios app using ionic 3 and xcode 9. But app resources not updating app icons and splash screen. I used 'Ionic cordova resources' and also tried  to place all app icons in images.xassets, but noting works. App still shows default app icon and splash screens

Xcode screenshot

[image]

Comment: What happens if you run `ionic cordova resources --force`? The `force` flag should remove the old icon/splash screen and create the new ones...

Comment: @sebaferreras .. I tried with ''--force"..it runs completely but nothing changed

Comment: what is the icon and splash image sizes you are using in your resources folder?

Comment: @SurajRao ..  i'm using the same sizes  and icon names as default icons. If sizes mismatch , xcode shows warning but here is nothing like that

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me by doing the following:

1. Remove ios/android under platform directory
2. Build the app